# How to only allow one htaccess file?

Tags: apache-2.4

I know that `.htaccess` files slightly decrease the performance of apache. Since I need one for WordPress, is there any way to only allow that one `.htaccess` file so apache doesn't search for one in each directory(something like include for the htaccess file)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have found a solution:
In `apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
    #Include the .htaccess file
    Include /var/www/html/.htaccess
</Directory>
```

from what I understand, this will cause changes to not go live immediately(which I tested by renaming `.htaccess`, and the rewrite rules still worked)

Comment: No, Include configurations are not dynamically updated. htaccess through allowoverride is because they are meant for non-admin users who can't change the main config or restart the server. You should just copy paste the contents of those files inside the directory and/or try to simplify whatever of those directives  to virtualhost context instead, since per-dir configurations  (also .htaccess is per-dir) tend to be more complex and convoluted.

Comment: That’s what I said: changes will NOT go live immediately. The reason I don’t copy and paste is because it’s easier to restart Apache every now and then when I add plugins to WordPress that use htaccess, than it is to copy and paste with nano(especially caching plugins that use a hundred lines)